# C# covariance in a non generic class

Tags: c#, covariance

i really searched in all the covariance questions, and nothing looks like my problem.

I have a user control (this class cant be generic, for obvious reasons), and it looks like this:

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private BaseDao<object> _dao;
    private AppointmentMapping<object> _mapping;

    // I need these 2 generics to type safe the mapping/dao relation
    public void RegisterPersistence<T>(BaseDao<T> dao, AppointmentMapping<T> mapping)
   {
        // These two dont work. even with safe and unsafe casting.
        _dao = dao;
        _mapping = mapping;
   }
}
```

I already tried to store a delegate for covariance, interfaces and etc. It just dont store the object!
How can i achieve this? This is easily achievable with Java.

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with a `UserControl`. It can happen with any classes. You could probably consider editing this question to make it more "generic"...

Comment: I don't know the definition of BaseDao and AppointmentMapping, but if they are indeed generic classes, there is no co/contra-variance on the generic parameter in C#

Comment: The point is that you don't tell how you want to access the fields later on. Surely storing them as `object` will work. If you need to access that fields later in another code piece, you either need to have `<T>` again and you can then cast to object to the right implementation, or register the code that uses the fields in an delegate (of type Action), e.g. and execute it later on. Otherwise make BaseDoa and AppointmentMapping implement non-generic interfaces and use that for the field type.

Comment: I dont need to use the T again. I will work with them using reflection. Just storing the instances would solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this the following.
The idea is to capture the T at usage time and store it in a class that "knows what to do later". Then reference the item in your class via an interface (omitting type information).
Later on call the stored value via the interface. That way you don't need to refactor your generic classes to implement certain interfaces.

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
  {

    // hold a reference to the helper - no generics needed here -> "covariant"
    private IHelper helper;

    // I need this 2 generics to type safe the relation between the mapping and the dao
    public void RegisterPersistence<T>(BaseDao<T> dao, AppointmentMapping<T> mapping) {
      // "pass <T>" for later usage
      this.helper = new HelperImpl<T>(dao, mapping);
    }

    // use the stored values...
    public void doStuff() {
      helper.doStuff();
    }

    // the non generic interface
    private interface IHelper
    {
      void doStuff();
    }

    // a generic implementation for storing the items *and* using them.
    private sealed class HelperImpl<T> : IHelper
    {
      private readonly BaseDao<T> dao;
      private readonly AppointmentMapping<T> mapping;

      public HelperImpl(BaseDao<T> dao, AppointmentMapping<T> mapping) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.mapping = mapping;
      }

      public void doStuff() {
        this.dao.foo();
        this.mapping.foo();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Made it and the result is sweeeeeeeeet.

Comment: If this is possible, then it is also possible to re-factor the original objects into non generic bases which could be stored in the user control directly.

Answer (score 1):

To use covariance and contravariance is necessary a Interface!

Covariance: `IInterface<out T>`

Contravariance: `IInterface<in T>`

Check this link for more information:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/08/31/understanding-csharp-covariance-and-contravariance-3-samples.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is to the best of my knowledge impossible.

Like Sebastian said, what you can do is have

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private object _dao;
    private object _mapping;

    // I need this 2 generics to type safe the relation between the mapping and the dao
    public void RegisterPersistence<T>(BaseDao<T> dao, AppointmentMapping<T> mapping)
   {
        _dao = dao;
        _mapping = mapping;
   }


   public BaseDao<T> GetDao<T>()
   {
       return _dao as BaseDao<T>;
   }

   public AppointmentMapping<T> GetAppointmentMapping<T>()
   {
       return _mapping as AppointmentMapping<T>;
   }
}
```

Comment: It won't work, because I will use the objects inside the class.

Comment: This is difficult, or like I said, impossible..What do you want to do?

Comment: Its just that, store the DAO inside the UserControl and user later on the events to persist the data.

Comment: You should either re-factor your repositories so they don't require generics on this level, e.g. use a interface which has only a Save() method, since it knows what type it has anyhow. Or you could save them externally where you know what type of objects you have, e.g. in a save customer button action.

Answer (score 0):

H.alex is right, best thing would be to move the generic bit on a different layer so you can make the class generic and then have generic class members rather than objects. The class must be able to infer the generic type or you'll have to write something like:

```
public class BaseDao<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private BaseDao<object> _dao;

    public void RegisterPersistence<T>(BaseDao<T> dao)
    {
        _dao = Activator.CreateInstance<BaseDao<object>>();
        //need to map each member of BaseDao
        _dao.Item = dao.Item;
    }    
}
```

which is clearly not maintainable as you have to take care of mapping all members on the new instance.

Comment: this is not a covariance, it is an invariance, you will not be able to cast

Comment: true, here to add a covariant interface the class need to include the <T> constraint (coming from the interface). As said best thing would be to move the generic part outside the MyUserControl class.